# Canon EdSDK Error kEdsStateEvent_Shutdown

Tags: macos, edsdk

I have a Canon 7d using EdSdk 2.14 on OSX.  If I Open a session and leave it alone for 4 mins I always get a shutdown event triggered.  Here is my event callback.  Why does it always call shutdown?  I have also tried to call kEdsCameraCommand_ExtendShutDownTimer to extend the timer but this does not help.  Anyone else run into similar issues.  Not sure if its my Camera or just the SDK is not up to par.

```
EdsError EDSCALLBACK handleStateEvent( EdsUInt32 inEvent, EdsUInt32 inParam, EdsVoid * inContext)
{
EdsError error = EDS_ERR_OK;
CameraController *controller = (CameraController *)inContext;

switch(inEvent)
{
case kEdsStateEvent_Shutdown:
    [CameraEventListener fireEvent: controller command: @"closing" withArgument: 0];
    break;
default:
    break;
}
return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want that your camera automatically shuts down, either:
-configure it in the cameras menu,
-or use ExtendShutDownTimer. To do that you have to catch the WillSoonShutDown event and not the Shutdown event.
The Shutdown event is too late, since the camera is off already and can't get switched on from the computer. It should be used to stop the user from interacting with the camera and maybe release some camera related data.